# How to find the service contracts in a wsdl file?

Tags: wsdl, return-type

I have a `wsdl` file to analyze. There, I got to find the `service contracts`.

Part of the `wsdl` file:

```
 <wsdl:types>

 <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
 <s:element name="SubmitApplication">
  <s:complexType>
   <s:sequence>
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="doc" type="tns:DocApplication" />
     <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="submittedDate" type="s:dateTime" />
     <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="category" type="s:unsignedByte" />
   </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
 </s:element>

  <s:complexType name="DocApplication">
   <s:sequence>
     <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="docId" type="s:int" />
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="title" type="s:string" />
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="author" type="s:string" />
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description" type="s:string" />
     <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="datechanged" type="s:dateTime" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

 <s:element name="SubmitApplicationResponse">
  <s:complexType>
   <s:sequence>
     <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SubmitApplicationResult" type="s:boolean" />
   </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
```

I've figured out that one of the service contracts can be

```
DocApplication (int docId, string title, string author, string description, date datechanged) ;
```

Here, how to find the return type (whether `int` /`void` / etc) from the `wsdl` file?